# Automatically Combine Duplicate Value and Rank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet, google-query-language

In Google Sheets, I am trying to rank a table of people to find out who contributes the highest numbers.

Sometimes one person contributes multiple times so I need to sum them up before ranking.

[image]

The issue is the table will be updated with new names every few hours so I don't want to use SUMIF and manually add those new names. Is there a formula to automate that process? Thanks!

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such [md tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in E2:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(A2:B; 
 "select A,sum(B) 
  where B is not null 
  group by A 
  order by sum(B) desc 
  label sum(B)''");; 1)
```